# Range of ballistic missile on flat world

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

The range of the Trident 2 submarine-launched ballistic missile is stated to be at least twelve thousand kilometres - the exact figure is classified, but taking it as 12,000 km exactly for purposes of discussion. That's on Earth, where the range is increased by the horizon dropping away under the missile in flight.

Suppose you fired such a missile on a flat world where the surface gravity is still 1g (or something like Larry Niven's Ringworld, where the radius is large enough that it can be treated as flat in this context). What would the range of the missile be in that scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the missile is ballistic, we might discuss an unpowered ballistic trajectory without air resistance, and ignore earth rotation.

As long as the initial velocity is less than [escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) the projectile will return to earth. The range depends on initial velocity and direction an can vary from zero up to a complete orbit. If the initial velocity is greater than escape velocity and the direction points away from surface the projectile will never come back. See also [Newton's cannonball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_cannonball).

In a flat world with infinite extent gravity is constant, i.e independent of location and height. The maximum range is then [obtained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Conditions_at_the_final_position_of_the_projectile) with an initial angle of 45 degrees and is $$d = \frac{v^2}{g}$$ where $v$ is the initial velocity and $g$ the gravitational acceleration. Note that this does not hold in a ring world.

Comment: According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(missile)) the velocity attained 2 minutes after launch is about 6000 m/s which would give a range of about 3700 km with your expression, with a maximum height of 1800 km. In reality the missile engines run for a while longer, so calling it "ballistic" is a bit of a misnomer; this also means that your expression is _very_ approximate.

Comment: Yes, this is why I listed the assumptions made. In fact the ballistic trajectory starts above ground, and air resistance is probably not negligible. However, the expression given for a flat world does not hold for the earth.